# Xamarin.Forms - Is there a mechanism to "include" a partial view?

Tags: xamarin, user-controls, templating, xamarin.forms

Does Xamarin.Forms have a concept of includes?

I'm creating an app that has a shared header across all pages. Is there a way to create the header once and include it on all pages? Better yet, is there a way to create a template or a reusable layout that you can put all content inside for each page? It would be a similar concept to .NET MVC's `_Layout` file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you need is the ControlTemplate introduced in 2.1.0.

Create a control template in your ResourceDictionary in Application.Resources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Mobile.App">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="MainPageTemplate">
        <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="Header Content" FontSize="24" />         
          <ContentPresenter />
        </StackLayout>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then in your ContentPage, assigned the ControlTemplate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               x:Class="Mobile.MainPage"
               ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MainPageTemplate}">

  <Label Text="Main Page Content" FontSize="18" />

</ContentPage>
```

Then you end up with

[image]

Referenced from: http://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-page-templates/

Comment: If I apply a control template at page level as opposed to application level, can derived classes use this control template?

Comment: @jbyrd - I haven't tried it but you should be able to. Create a new ControlTemplate(), and add the controls. Then assign it to the ControlTemplate property on the page.

Answer (score 13):

Yes. You can use User Controls for this. You can Use XAML or code only. I'll explain the XAML way.

Just add a new XAML Page and change the root type from `ContentPage` to `StackLayout`. The root type can be every other layout or control. You have to decide what fits best.

**MyControl.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App6.MyControl">
    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Age}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding CatAmount}" />
</StackLayout>
```

We bind the properties `Name, Age, CatAmount` to three different labels. We assume, that the `BindingContext` of this control is an object of type `PersonData` (see below).
In your Code behind, you have to change the type as well.

**MyControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyControl : StackLayout
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In your page, you have to add a new namespace (e.g. `local` that points to you assembly, e.g. `App6` or `MyApp.Whatever`). Then you can use it via `local:MyControl`. In our example control, we bind the `BindingContext` to `Person`, wich is a Property of our Page's BindingContext, that is (in our case) the page itself. If your control is in a sub namespace, you have to change the namespace part accordingly.

**Page2.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App6;assembly=App6"
             x:Class="App6.Page2">
    <local:MyControl BindingContext="{Binding Person}"></local:MyControl>
</ContentPage>
```

**Page2.xaml.cs**

```
public class PersonData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int CatAmount { get; set; }
}

public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public PersonData Person { get; set; }

    public Page2()
    {
        Person = new PersonData {Age = 28, Name = "Sven", CatAmount = 2};
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

And in your mentioned Scenario, you can simply inherit from `ContentPage` and add your common elements and use you inherited Page as base class of your pages.

**TemplatedPage - Xamarin.Forms 2.1**

With Xamarin.Forms 2.1 they introduced `TemplatedPage`. You find the example here: http://xfcomplete.net/general/2016/01/20/control-templates/ . The `LoginView` example with the `ContentPresenter` fits your scenario exactly.